# Debugging failed tasks in Spark Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I a few of the order of 1 per mil tasks that fail, the whole stage completes successfully but I'm having difficulties to understand where it is coming from.

It happens "randomly" on different nodes. I increased the `timeouts` at the Cassandra level.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Which tasks? Can you include the `nodetool tpstat` output? (if those are what you are referring too). Or do you mean queries are failing?

Comment: I meant Spark tasks (as I understand a job is composed of stages composed of tasks).

Comment: You can increase debugging levels on the executors, it may be a single task which hits a C* token range which is extremely dense or contains a very very wide partition?

Comment: Might be a very large partition. I'll investigate in that direction.